# Why is a Zero Vector Space a Vector Space?

Tags: linear-algebra

The first example in my Linear Algebra textbook states this is so by stating the example satisfies axiom $4$, which says there is zero vector, there is an object $u$ in which $0 + u = u + 0 = u$, where $0$ is the zero vector and $u$ is an object or a set of real number.

Is there not already a violation in axiom 1 where the zero space is not closed under addition because the vector space is missing another object v?

Comment: Where does the the 'closed under addition' axiom say you need to add *two different* things together?!

Comment: Axiom 1 says if u and v are objects in V, then u + v is in V.

Comment: $u$ and $v$ don't have to be different.

Comment: I think i am confused. Am i supposed to think axiom 1 is automatically satisfied even if there is one object in V? There is no mention of object v but only object u.

Comment: to be closed you need to know that whatever in the set you add together you'll stay in the set. If the set contains just the zero vector then you only need to ask yourself "does $0+0$ belong to my set".

Comment: Please look up the exact definition of a vector space. "if there is zero vector, there is an object $u$ in which $0 + u = u + 0 = u$, where $0$ is the zero vector and $u$ is an object or a set of real number" is wrong and quite confusing. What is an *object* and why are *sets of real numbers* involved? State the exact definition before trying to figure out if $\{0\}$ is a candidate.

Comment: So u and v can be the same object? How come? I wish the textbook pointed this out. A vector space is something that satisfies all 10 axioms.

Comment: They're variables. They're assumed to take any value in their domain, of course they can be the same value. Or different values. Or any pair of values in the domain!

Comment: I've read that some sets of definitions assume explicitly (and some accidentally) that $1 \ne 0$, in which case $\{\{0\}, +, \cdot\}$ would not be a vector space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The zero set is closed under addition: $0+0=0$. It is closed under scalar multiplication: $\lambda\cdot 0=0$. It is non-empty. Hence it is a vector space, and in fact the only one of dimension $0$ (up to isomorphism and once the field is fixed).

Comment: the only one up to isomorphism, and when the ground field is fixed.

Comment: But the example said there is only one object in V. 0 +  0 is the same as u + v and you are already using 2 objects.

Comment: The definition of vector space you take any element $x\in V$ and add it to any element $y\in V$, which can be equal or not to $x$, and want that $x+y\in V$. If $V$ contains exactly one element there is only one thing to check: that $0+0$ belongs to the set.

Comment: @Ittay Weiss, I added the precision.

Comment: When you say equal do you mean their values being equal? So if V has only one element, 0 + 0 is that element? Is that definition not only for axiom 1and not the definition for a vector space? Do objects and elements have the same meaning?

Comment: In a vector space you have a map wich takes two elements $x,y\in V$ and gives you back one element, which is denoted by $x+y$. This map is called "addition". Hence, $x+y$ is really one element. In the case of $0$ we get then $0+0$, which is a vector, and is equal to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Axiom 1, as you report it, is

> if $u$ and $v$ are objects in $V$, then $u + v$ is in $V$

I wouldn't classify this among the axioms: it's just the requirement that *an operation is defined on $V$*. However, a correct reading of the statement is

> for every $u\in V$ and every $v\in V$, $u+v\in V$

Nothing whatsoever prevents $u$ and $v$ from denoting the same object (or, better, from being substituted with the same object in $V$); are you going to doubt that $2+2$ can be performed in the natural numbers?

An operation on $V$ is just a map
$$
V\times V\to V
$$
and as such it *must* be defined also on pairs of the form $(x,x)$. Is there an operation
$$
\{0\}\times\{0\}\to\{0\}
$$
that makes $\{0\}$ into an abelian group? Surely so! There's only one map! Can you define a map $F\times\{0\}\to\{0\}$? Yes, of course, there's only one.

Is $\{0\}$ a vector space under these operations? Yes, indeed. Can you falsify the associative property or any other of the requested properties?

So, yes, any one element set is a vector space (on whatever field you fix), because there's only one way to define the operations on it.

Answer (score -1):

The zero set satisfies the two properties of a subspace.

i) Closed under addition. $0+0=0$

ii) Closed under scalar multiplication $\lambda(0)=0$.

My previous edit was naively wrong.

Comment: your argument does not show that $\{0\}$ is a vector space.

Comment: You're saying that $0$ is in every vector space, the OP wants to know why $\{0\}$ (a singleton set) is a vector space.

Comment: Ah ok I'll edit